# Merge join 2 csv files with multiple null values columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do a join on two CSV files to get the unique values out of both files. For this particular problem, I am using the merge function of pandas lib. the CSV files I am using are having multiple columns and various rows have Null values for certain attributes/columns. I am trying to use `astype('Int32')`, but how can I use it for multiple columns at a time. Do I have to run some loop or is it possible otherwise?

In short I guess my question would be how to apply `astype` on multiple columns?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

# reading csv files
data1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv')

# using merge function by setting how='right'
output3 = pd.merge(data1, data2,
                on='LOAN_NO',
                how='right')

# displaying result
print(output3)
```

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
  
# reading csv files
data1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv')
  
# using merge function by setting how='outer'
output4 = pd.merge(data1, data2, 
                   on='LOAN_NO', 
                   how='outer')
  
# displaying result
print(output4)
```

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

# reading two csv files
data1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv')

# using merge function by setting how='inner'
output1 = pd.merge(data1, data2,
                on='LOAN_NO',
                how='inner')

# displaying result
print(output1)
```